# fonts not working when str_limit helper is used in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, strip-tags

I have a **notice** page where it shows the **title and brief description** of the notice through **str_limit helper function**. and **notice_show** page shows the **full description**. I posted a notice using **Kantipur font (used for Nepali typing) in tinymce editor**. 
The notice_show page shows the description as it is expected to show but the notice page shows some annoying characters like **hgHof]lt ax'd'vL SofDk;sf] egf{ ;DalGw ;"rgf      &nbsp...**

notice_show page directly pulls the description from the database by

```
{{$notice ->description }}
```

notice page truncates description by

```
{{ (str_limit(strip_tags($notice->description), 100)) }}
```

Images of notice and notice_show pages are upload below:
[image: Notice page]

[image: Notice_show page]

Comment: FYI: `strip_tags` is unnecessary as Blade takes care of escaping the output.

Comment: And the problem is probably related to text encoding. Here's how the `str_limit` function works: https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Str.php#L216

Comment: Does using `{{ $notice ->description }}`, without the `str_limit` show you all the text as it should?

Comment: @Robert. Thanks for your concern. The problem was with the text encoding as advised by Jeffrey.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use this :

```
{!! (str_limit(strip_tags($notice->description), 100)) !!}
```